# Collection pluck by relation id and get count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have  Project and Country Model. There is a many to many relations. I get projects with countries. Result is below

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "account_id" => 1
    "start_date" => "Jul 2012"
    "end_date" => "Aug 2013"
    "countries" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "id" => 148
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▶]
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  3 => array:5 [▶]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

I wont to get all unique countries count. In the now I do it with this way

```
$projects->pluck('countries')->collapse()->pluck('id')->unique()->count()
```

Question. Can I use pluck with nested relation column and has any more shortly and good solution?? for example like this

```
$projects->pluck('countries.id')->count();
```

Comment: nested pluck isn't possible since it returns array.

Comment: I think your own solution is good.

Comment: @MisaGH I get this solution `$projects->pluck('countries.*.id')->collapse()->unique()->count()` but I think there is more good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$projects->pluck('countries.*.id')->flatten()->unique()->count()
```

You can't use:

```
$projects->pluck('countries.id')...
```

Because countries is an array of arrays.
But you can use the `'countries.*.id'` on those cases

Answer (score 2):

Or the other way round...

```
Country::whereHas('projects', function ($query) {
    // $query->where(); if you want to limit the projects
})->count();
```

You get unique countries since your fetching from the countries table

Comment: you solution is good. but I get this data using more complex query. I get it  account->projects->countries nested query. I can not change initial query, and I do not use second query

Comment: Oki, not applicable to this question but I think that `whereHas` accepts dot-notation for multiple nest levels, like `Account::whereHas('projects.countries', ...`

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution

```
$projects->groupBy('countries.*.id')->count();
```